# Connect Azure Key Vault with Certificate using SpringBoot's application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, azure-keyvault

> I have used the application.properties to connect Azure Key Vault:

```
azure.keyvault:
enabled: true
token-acquire-timeout-seconds: 60
uri: https://*.vault.azure.net/
client-id: 'put dev client id here'
client-key: 'put dev client key here'
secret.keys: datamart-datasource-url,datamart-datasource-username,datamart-datasource-password
```

> But, we have changed our requirements. Currently, we want to connect AKV using Client-Certificate instead of Client-Key.

> What is the solution to connect AKV using Certificate???

> Note:- You can play with Certificate in any format ( like Base64String or etc.) to connect AKV using SpringBoot property (Application.properties).

Answer (score 0):

It seems no document about connecting key vault with Certificates(in application) in spring boot, even no detailed explanation about `client-key` property.

You could request `/token` endpoint to get access token, then call [key vault Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/) with the token.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token 

scope=https://vault.azure.net/.default
&client_id=xxx
&client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer
&client_assertion={An assertion (a JSON web token)}
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Note: add the permission of Azure Key Vault and grant admin consent for your tenant.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below properties to connect AKV using a Certificate.

************Application.yml************

```
azure.keyvault:
  enabled: true
  token-acquire-timeout-seconds: 60
  uri: https://*-akv-*-mi-01.vault.azure.net/
  client-id: '76b******-4157-81cc-042bddba37a6'
  certificate:
    path: 'g-spn-0d-datainsights01-myinsights-01-20201112.pfx'
  tenant-id: '348a129******466e-a7af-4ad1a1b79713'
  secret.keys: datamart-datasource-url,datamart-datasource-username,datamart-datasource-password
```

************Application.properties************

```
azure.keyvault.enabled: true
  azure.keyvault.token-acquire-timeout-seconds: 60
  azure.keyvault.uri: https://*-akv-*-mi-01.vault.azure.net/
  azure.keyvault.client-id: '76b******-4157-81cc-042bddba37a6'
  azure.keyvault.certificate.path: 'g-spn-**myinsights-01-20201112.pfx'
  azure.keyvault.tenant-id: '348a129******466e-a7af-4ad1a1b79713'
  azure.keyvault.secret.keys: datasource-username,datasource-password
```

*******Dependency*******

```
compile('com.microsoft.azure:azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter:2.0.+')
compile('com.microsoft.azure:azure-spring-boot-starter:2.0.+')
compile('com.microsoft.azure:azure-keyvault:1.0.0')
compile('com.azure:azure-security-keyvault-certificates:4.1.0')
compile('com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:8.20')
```